# the command ... returned a non-zero code 100 docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, openvino

I'm trying to install OpenVino on my Raspberry using Docker.

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM raspbian/stretch

ARG INSTALL_DIR="/opt/intel/inference_engine_vpu_arm"

RUN apt-get -y update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get autoremove && \
    apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
        build-essential \
    cmake \
        cpio \
        lsb-release \
        pciutils \
        python3.5 \
        python3.5-dev \
        python3-pip \
        python3-setuptools \
    ffmpeg \
    libjpeg-dev \
        libtiff5-dev \
        libjasper-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libavcodec-dev \
        libavformat-dev \
        libswscale-dev \
        libv4l-dev \
        libxvidcore-dev \
        libx264-dev \
        libgtk2.0-dev \
        libgtk-3-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        gfortran \
        libgstreamer1.0-0 \
        libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0

RUN usermod -a -G users "$(whoami)"

COPY inference_engine_vpu_arm $INSTALL_DIR 

RUN sed -i "s|<INSTALLDIR>|$INSTALL_DIR|" $INSTALL_DIR/bin/setupvars.sh && \
    echo "source $INSTALL_DIR/bin/setupvars.sh" >> $HOME/.bashrc

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source $INSTALL_DIR/bin/setupvars.sh && /bin/bash $INSTALL_DIR/install_dependencies/install_NCS_udev_rules.sh"]

RUN pip3 install numpy

RUN apt autoremove -y && \
    rm -rf  /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

But I have this error when I try to build:

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update..... returned a non-zero code: 100

Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a some google search it seems the error happens because the apt daemon is not able to connect to the configured repositories. This is likely since the base image was not updated for a while as i can see on docker hub.

If you not familiar with the available repositories you can generate them easily with online tools such as: https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/index.php?generate

You can put them into the docker image with a simple COPY command like

```
COPY sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

where the first argument refers to a local file, the second to the docker image

Comment: i failed to reproduce it locally. Where does this image actually getting executed? Containers are using the default docker bridge ? Default docker bridge can access the internet ?

Comment: How can i check if "Containers are using the default docker bridge"?

Comment: There is a built in command for that. Use docker network ls and it will list the created network interfaces for the container. You can get more details about what is using the interface with the docker network inspect command. You should be able to identify the containers based on their id.